# $ \left ( \frac{\partial u}{\partial T} \right )_p= \left ( \frac{\partial u}{\partial T} \right )_V $ value

Tags: thermodynamics

I am trying to derive certain formulas and and I feel like the following 
expression is good for my derivation.
$$ \left ( \frac{\partial u}{\partial T} \right )_p= \left ( \frac{\partial u}{\partial T} \right )_V $$ 
I am trying to say that the above expression is true because of first law of thermodynamics.
any suggestions weather if this approach is good or not

Comment: What's the equation for $u$ in terms of $T, p$ and $V$?

Answer (score 1):

$$dU=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_VdT+\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_TdV$$
$$dV=\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_PdT+\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_TdP$$so

$$dU=\left[\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V+\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\right]dT+\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_TdP$$
So, $$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_P=\left[\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V+\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\right]$$
According to this, your equation is correct for an ideal gas, but not for a real gas beyond the ideal gas region.

Comment: @VincentFraticelli  Your equation for Cp is incorrect.  Cp is the partial derivative of **enthalpy** H with respect to temperature at constant pressure (not the partial derivative of internal energy U with respect to temperature at constant pressure).  And, who said Cp and Cv are equal?

Comment: OK ! I had a moment of confusion !